# How to access Picasa Api url in Descending Order

Tags: android, json, api, sorting, picasa

I am making an android app using picasa web album. I have implemented the code to access the images using api. but i am unable to put that images in descending order so that i can access new images at top of the grid view.
I am using url like this to access code.

https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/_PICASA_USER_/albumid/_ALBUM_ID_?alt=json

Please help me to get url for order(sorting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so much information... But an idea will be when you read your json and create a List, use `myList.add(0, picURL)` instead of `myList.add(picURL)`, that will add the URL to the first position each time, instead of adding it to the end.